# How to disable past dates from Bootstrap Datepaginator

Tags: javascript, php

How to disable past dates from Bootstrap Datepaginator, i want to show  pagination from current date and disable the past dates

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the documentation - https://github.com/jonmiles/bootstrap-datepaginator. It looks like you want to use the `startDate` option.

```
var options = {
    startDate: '2015-07-30'
}
$('#paginator').datepaginator(options);
```

The option will either take a string (as in my example), or a `moment` object (http://momentjs.com/). I would suggest using moment as it makes working with date objects super easy, and in general is a good addition to any project that works with dates. `moment()` would return todays date, so you could re-write the above example as follows;

```
var options = {
    startDate: moment()
}
$('#paginator').datepaginator(options);
```

Comment: i add this., but not able to disable past dates.any keyword like startDate.In calender also showing previous dates.

Answer (score 1):

```
Try this code :

var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!

var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
if(dd<10){
    dd='0'+dd
} 
if(mm<10){
    mm='0'+mm
} 
var today = yyyy+'-'+mm+'-'+dd;
var options = { startDate: today }
$('#paginator').datepaginator(options);
```

Set current date as the start date

Comment: i used the same ,but  im able to select previous dates and from calendar also .i can search previous date also. im not able to disable the previous dates. in my case i dont want to select previous dates. and current date should come at the first of pagination.